# Can Multiple Java Classes Contain GroupAccount Object for a SaaS?

Tags: java, class, object, account, saas

I am building a SaaS app in Java. Managers will be able to create a "GroupAccount" and create user accounts that will be underneath the group account. I've started to realize that for many of the app's pages, I need to reference this GroupAccount. My question is, can multiple classes have private fields of this GroupAccount object or is this poor design?

The only other way I could think to do it is to have the GroupAccount object be a private field of just one class, and then have the others classes have a private field of that class instead, rather than the GroupAccount class.

However, for the database queries this would mean I would have to do JOIN statements and such. It would be a lot easier to just have most of my classes contain a field of the GroupAccount. Is this an okay thing to do?

Comment: You are reusing the word "classes" too much - which "classes" do you mean in "can multiple classes have private fields of this GroupAccount object" - are you referring to page controllers, or users, or ...?   I would say if you have a page that can only be  accessed by logged-in users, then I would have a GroupAccountService that will get that user's details from the context;  whether it then accesses the database, and/or JOINS and/or caches would then simply be internal implementation encapsulated within that service.

Comment: I have classes such as "UserAccount" "Order" and "Task". Users place orders and orders have tasks. Would it be okay for all of these classes to have a GroupAccount object as a private field, or since Task also has an Order object as a private field, should GroupAccount only be a private field of the Order class?

Comment: In general, this sort of "redundancy" is to be avoided, and instead the DRY principle applies - eg, if I have an Order for a customer, then the OrderLines should not have a reference to the customer as well.  As always, there may be special cases, but starting with correct principles leads to less pain in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So from what I understand, there’s really no need to have GroupAccount private fields in these classes at all? I can just instantiate a GroupAccount object when it’s needed since my database will have a foreign key in all the tables to the GroupAccounts table?

Comment: Your database should certainly not have redundant attributes/columns (check out "3rd Normal Form").  If tables have a seemingly-redundant references, then you need to determine why.  Eg, extending my previous analogy, if both Order and Orderline tables have an Address column, is it needed functionally on Orderline (eg some items are allowed to be shipped elsewhere), or not (eg might be "de-normalised" for performance, or could just be bad design!).  Your Java classes need to mirror the functional requirements from the database.